# Referencing assets in dotnet application after webpack bundle

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack

The project I am working on uses vue and vuetify with dotnet core MVC. A directory is created to contain vue code but after compilation, the asset reference is not consistent. The bundle goes to the *wwwroot* folder and the bundled assets try to reference that folder but it cannot because of dotnet. I used vue.config.js for the bundle configuration. When the project is run the asset references https://localhost:5000/wwwroot/build/img/image1.png but the correct location is https://localhost:5000/build/img/image1.png

How do I make it reference the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

set publicPath to 'wwwroot' in your vue config file
[see detail](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Comment: I have it set in the vue.config.js file